# Displaying categories and thei subcategories in OctoberCMS backend form

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am developing a plugin using `Builder` plugin to display items and their categories and subcategories.

`Item` model have `$belongsTo` relations with `Category` and `SubCategory` models, also `Category` has `$belongsToMany` relation with `SubCategory`, and I created a form which has a `relation widget` to display the categories, but I don't know how to display the subcategories `relation widget` which are for the selected category and when user select new category a diffrent list of subcategories will be displayed in sub categories drop down box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my previous post was deleted because I simply included a link and a short description but not code.

What you are looking for are "Field dependencies":

https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dependencies

You won't be able to do it all through the Builder plugin- you will have to write some code. Here is an example:

The fields.yaml file for your model:

```
country:
    label: Country
    type: dropdown

state:
    label: State
    type: dropdown
    dependsOn: country
```

Then, in the controller:

```
public function getCountryOptions()
{
    return ['au' => 'Australia', 'ca' => 'Canada'];
}

public function getStateOptions()
{
    if ($this->country == 'au') {
        return ['act' => 'Capital Territory', 'qld' => 'Queensland', ...];
    }
    elseif ($this->country == 'ca') {
        return ['bc' => 'British Columbia', 'on' => 'Ontario', ...];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for your answer but I needed to make it dynamic, I found a test plugin which shows this https://github.com/octoberrain/test-plugin

Comment: That does make it dynamic- the getCountryOptions() and getStateOptions() in the example above is just an example with hard coded data. You can query the database or do whatever other calculations you might need to do to generate the array that you want to return.